# Dialogflow Not able to use Parameter in response

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to use Dialogflow, and following their guide [building-your-first-agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXGxm.png) to create an intent with response

However, if I use the parameter inside the response, it will return 'not available' from default response. Does anyone know why it is happening?

From the picture, it will response the correct sentence without parameter. the response is not available when using parameter.

[image: Result of response with parameter]
[image: Result of response without parameter]

Diagnostic info

without parameter

```
{
  "id": "aa316e0a-7f41-46cb-a03c-03c13d80ae6b",
  "timestamp": "2018-05-16T18:31:11.858Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "turn on asdkasjd",
    "action": "",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {
      "cameraName": ""
    },
    "contexts": [],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "41b046bc-65ea-425b-8a33-9e37c44dddf4",
      "webhookUsed": "false",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "intentName": "opencamera"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "speech": "Sorry I don't know",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "OK. I will try to turn on"
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 0.9300000071525574
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success"
  },
  "sessionId": "e488d71a-a21e-4cf0-bfcb-13b4a36fd811"
}
```

[image: Training Phase]

Comment: Can you update the question to include the training phrases you are using for each one and the diagnostic info for the Intent where it is supposed to use the parameter, but doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the [`@sys:given-name`](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities#names) parameter in an attempt to match "camera" or "camera two", but neither of these are a "given name", which is meant to match the name given to a person (as opposed to their family name), not the name given to a device.

In these cases, it is using some rough matching and determining that "turn on" matches enough of the sample phrase to match the Intent, but that there is no value that matches the name part of it. Since that parameter isn't required, the Intent matches without a value for the parameter.

There are a few things you can do to remedy this, depending on your exact needs:

- You may wish to mark the parameter as required. (This doesn't solve the name issue, but will make sure it is either matched or the user is prompted for the value.)
- You can use the `@sys:any` entity type. This should match anything the user includes for the parameter.
- If you have some defined names, you can [define your own entity type](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities#developer_entities).

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you have not added any phrases in 'Training Phrases' section above 'Action and Parameters' section. Please add those to train your agent to detect 'cameraName' parameter from phrases. Secondly, if you see your json, result->parameters->cameraName is empty. And if the parameter is empty, it cannot respond with a response that requires the parameter 'cameraName'. Try adding a third response under responses with parameters that does not uses parameter and see the result, it will return the third response and when it will detect the parameter, it will start showing response with the parameter.